# Transformation which split document and insert as multiple

Tags: javascript, node.js, marklogic, marklogic-8, marklogic-9

The only way i found to do it through MLCP, where you transformation has to return an array of format [{"uri": "some_uri1", "value": "newly_created_doc1"},{"uri": "some_uri2", "value": "newly_created_doc2"}]. This way after applying transformation with content pump there will be created these two documents from let's say some original document. My question is how to achieve the same result via node.js api or java api. For example with node.js I am able to apply transformation and it is creating this file as a single document with array of the style above.

My transformation:

```js
const common = require("/ext/home/common.sjs");

function createDocs(content, context) {

    var bets = content.value.xpath('//selections').toArray();
    var documents = [];

    for (var bet in bets) {
        var bookie_name = "Boylesports";
        var sport_name = "Football";
        var event_name = bets[bet].xpath('../../../../name').toString();

        if (/^Over \d+\.\d+$/.test(event_name)) {
            event_name = event_name.replace(/^Over (\d+)\.\d+$/, 1);
        } else {
            event_name;
        }

        var subevent_name = bets[bet].xpath('../../../../name').toString();

        if (/^Over \d+\.\d+$/.test(subevent_name)) {
            subevent_name = subevent_name.replace(/^Over (\d+)\.\d+$/, 1);
        }
        else {
            subevent_name;
        }

        var subevent_id = bets[bet].xpath('../../../../idfoevent');
        var start_date = xdmp.parseDateTime("[Y0001]-[M01]-[D01]T[h01]:[m01]:[s01]", bets[bet].xpath('../../../../tsstart'));
        // var start_date = "2017-10-21T13:00:00Z";

        var market_name = bets[bet].xpath('../../name').toString();

        if (/^Handicap.+$/.test(market_name)) {
            market_name = market_name.replace(/^Handicap.+$/, "Handicaps");
        }
        if (/^Match Betting$/.test(market_name)) {
            market_name = market_name.replace(/^Match Betting$/, "Win Market");
        }
        else {
            market_name;
        }

        var market_id = bets[bet].xpath('../../idfomarket');
        var bet_name = bets[bet].xpath('name').toString();

        if (/^Aston Villa$/.test(bet_name)) {
            bet_name = bet_name.replace(/^Aston (Villa)$/, 1);
        }
        else {
            bet_name;
        }

        var bet_id = bets[bet].xpath('idfoselection');


        //Push to the list of documents
        var document = {};
        document.uri = common.convertToSlug(sport_name) + '/' + common.convertToSlug(event_name) + '/' + common.convertToSlug(subevent_name) + '/' + common.convertToSlug(market_name) + '/' + common.convertToSlug(bet_name);
        document.value = {
            'bookie_name': bookie_name,
            'sport_name': sport_name,
            'sport_slug': common.convertToSlug(sport_name),
            'event_name': event_name,
            'event_slug': common.convertToSlug(event_name),
            'subevent_name': subevent_name,
            'subevent_slug': common.convertToSlug(subevent_name),
            'subevent_id': subevent_id,
            'start_date': start_date,
            'market_name': market_name,
            'market_slug': common.convertToSlug(market_name),
            'market_id': market_id,
            'bet_name': bet_name,
            'bet_slug': common.convertToSlug(bet_name),
            'bet_id': bet_id
        };

        //Checks if objects with the same uri exist before pushing them
        if (documents.findIndex(x => x.uri == document.uri) === -1) documents.push(document);

        // documents.push(document);
    }
    return Sequence.from(documents);
}; 

exports.transform = createDocs;
```

My use in node.js:

```js
const axios = require("axios");
const db_client = require("../../database/connect").dbWriter;


axios.get("http://cache.boylesports.com/feeds/EUROFOOT2.json")
    .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response.data);

        var documents = [{uri: "http://cache.boylesports.com/feeds/EUROFOOT2.json",
                          content: response.data,
                          contentType: 'application/json',
                          collections: ["test"]}];



        db_client.documents.write({documents: documents, transform: ['js-example']}).result(
        function (response) {
            response.documents.forEach(function (document) {
                console.log('LOADED: ' + document.uri);
            });
        },
        function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    );

    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

Comment: not really sure how to answer the problem you have. but those url's look handy, I might use them in future.

Answer (score 0):

The Client API relies on REST transforms, that do not support the same kind of splitting into multiple documents. I was hoping to say that you could use DMSDK, but it looks like that relies on the same kind of transforms. Here an example that transforms documents after uploading into the database:

http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/java/data-movement#id_22702

Looks like you would have to go against the recommendation, and create a transform that would cause side-effects by doing `xdmp:document-insert` calls directly.

HTH!